# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error loading from Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I'm making a calc just for fun and I want to add a sound for when you press a button.

The error is:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

On this line of code:

```
let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "219069_annabloom_click1", ofType: "wav")!)
```

Comment: let alertsound= that is where the error starts

Comment: Print `Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "wav", subdirectory: nil)` to check if the resource is available in the bundle. If the sound is in a subdirectory, pass its name.

Comment: Force unwrapping is your enemy: remove the exclamation marks in your code and guard them to check the value is available, it will prevent your app from crashing - worst case you won't hear the sound but you can easily debug it checking if it guarded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem at here

```
 let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "219069_annabloom_click1", ofType: "wav")!)
```

meaning of this sign is `!` the value is not nil.
But I think you have't added the file correctly or there is issue with .wav extension double check it so it returns nil and app is crashed.

> Step 1: make sure you have added sound file correctly
>
> Step 2: verify extension is same in code and file

make sure the module is selected

[image]

Comment: the path is correct and when i remove the ! it ses

Comment: another error, here is what it ses fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: at which line you got the errror

Comment: ive figured it out, but now im getting the same prob audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: (alertsound)!)

Comment: which xcode you are using

Comment: on that line it ses it found nil, how can i make alertsound not nil, (its a url)

Comment: xcode 9, with swift 3

Comment: can you send screen shot of added sound file with attribute inspector

Comment: https://imgur.com/ZJkupbY

Comment: see i have added screen shot check weather module is selected on right side or not if not then check it. i marked it as red

Comment: more info how to add file https://stackoverflow.com/a/46243726/6028575

Comment: the image is not there

Comment: For some reason image is not display but you can check the link i given

Comment: ive just made it work, the problem was the path was wrong, thats why the url came up as nil, so srr, i really apreciate for all your help :D