# Use of undeclared identifier after porting swift code to objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to use a Class that was originally written in Swift

And following instruction find on the web that I should:

1. add the swift code to the target
2. adding a `#import "projectName-swift.h"` header in the `.m` file that I want to use the class defined in swift.

After doing that I try to use the class defined with swift Code like this:

```
  JPEG *jpeg = nil;
```

But the compiler complines that `Use of undeclared identifier 'JPEG'`

Here is what happened:

[image]

And here is the JPEG class:

```
import Foundation
import MobileCoreServices
import ImageIO

class JPEG {
    fileprivate let kFigAppleMakerNote_AssetIdentifier = "17"
    fileprivate let path : String

    init(path : String) {
        self.path = path
    }

    func read() -> String? {
        guard let makerNote = metadata()?.object(forKey: kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary) as! NSDictionary? else {
            return nil
        }
        return makerNote.object(forKey: kFigAppleMakerNote_AssetIdentifier) as! String?
    }

    func write(_ dest : String, assetIdentifier : String) {
        guard let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(URL(fileURLWithPath: dest) as CFURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, nil)
            else { return }
        defer { CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest) }
        guard let imageSource = self.imageSource() else { return }
        guard let metadata = self.metadata()?.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary! else { return }

        let makerNote = NSMutableDictionary()
        makerNote.setObject(assetIdentifier, forKey: kFigAppleMakerNote_AssetIdentifier as NSCopying)
        metadata.setObject(makerNote, forKey: kCGImagePropertyMakerAppleDictionary as String as String as NSCopying)
        CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(dest, imageSource, 0, metadata)
    }

    fileprivate func metadata() -> NSDictionary? {
        return self.imageSource().flatMap {
            CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex($0, 0, nil) as NSDictionary?
        }
    }

    fileprivate func imageSource() ->  CGImageSource? {
        return self.data().flatMap {
            CGImageSourceCreateWithData($0 as CFData, nil)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func data() -> Data? {
        return (try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)))
    }
}
```

What happended? how to make this work?

Comment: have you created the bridging header file for it ?

Comment: @GOPALVASANI yes I have, though it is not needed since I am porting swift to OC not vice versa

Comment: i have recentlly used this type functionalty in my current project and its work perfectlly , try once creating a bridging file for it , before it clear the path of bridging header from build setting . after that import the file. and let me know if it works or not ?

Comment: How have you added the file in your project? Are you using XCode 9.0?

Comment: @PuneetSharma yes and yes

Comment: Check the target for the Swift file. If you drag and drop a file/resource in XCode 9.0, it does not get added to the target. It is a known bug, which is fixed in XCode 9.1

Comment: Refer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45096667/1548190

Comment: @PuneetSharma thanks for remind that, but I just double checked, the Swift file indeed was added to the correct target

Comment: @armnotstrong: have you once build the application, before accessing the file in Objc class?

Comment: @PuneetSharma yes, I have

Comment: Check Build Settings of your target for Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name. It should have livewallpaper-swift.h

Comment: @PuneetSharma yes there is, and strange thing is that when adding a swift file to the project (not by drag and drop from other project) things will work fine, so I am wondering if the JPEG swift file is something wrong?

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve this by adding the `JPEG` swift class subclass of `NSObject`, don't know why is that, but now things work as promised.

Answer (score 0):

I finally make this work by making the `JPEG` swift class subclass of `NSObject` don't know why, but it works now.

```
class JPEG:NSObject {
    ...
}
```