# FileManager.enumerator returns nil while testing on ios device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

```
    let documentsPath = "Users/xxxx/Desktop/*******/iOSSimulator/"
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath)
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    print(FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: url.path))
```

I want to run my UI tests on actual iOS device.But while executing the test cases in real device i am getting nil (in the print statement).but the test cases are executing successfully on the simulator(here i am getting some value in print statement).

I am not able to figure out why it is returning the nil value in ios device.

Comment: There is no "/Users/xxxx/Desktop" directory on the device...

Comment: On a real device, there shouldn't be any `iOSSimulator` thing.

Comment: thank you @Kamran. I got the mistake i was doing. Is there any common location to put my files which can be picked up during execution of test cases?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving the wrong path(**let documentsPath = "Users/xxxx/Desktop/*******/iOSSimulator/"**). 
Real iOS device doesn't exist this path so you are getting nil.

Comment: Thank you @sanjeev. I have created some files in the documentsPath which i am using in test cases.Is there any common location where i can put my files ?

Comment: Please add your files in your project directory instead of your system's directory. To add files in your project directory "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096410/how-can-i-add-file-to-project-in-xcode-9". Now you can access your files.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving static document path , which may be exist in simulator but not in device . Use this for getting document path in swift

```
 if let documentsPathString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
            //This gives you the string formed path
    }

    if let documentsPathURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            //This gives you the URL of the path
    }
```